# switching power redundancy

Tags: power-supply, led, voltage, current, relay

I have a load (LEDs) that draws 36V, 5A. The circuit is made in this way:

Power Supply (AC-DC) -> LED Drivers (5 in parallel) -> LEDs (5 strips).

What component I need to install if I want to add second power supply but that ONLY when the first turns off (or stops working) the other immediately intervenes and the power supply to the LED Drivers is never cut off.

Comment: I would personally use a relay that is powered by the primary PSU and switch the secondary PSU off/on with it. That way the secondary PSU doesn't draw any current while it isn't used anyway. Disadvantage is that you'll have a subsecond interruption.

Comment: @jippie: Put a large enough BFC across the load and the relay's switching time can become inconsequential.

Comment: @EMFields Yeah I did think of that, but then I realized 5A load would need a serious BFC and decided to skipt that remark. Say 5V drop at 5A during 1 second equals 1F if formulae-memory serves me right and the napkin calculations are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is with diode switching

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQet9l.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

D1 and D2 are high-current diodes, preferably Schottky for low voltage drop.

There will be a slight loss of efficiency due to heating of the diodes, but for good Schottkys the loss should be in the range of 2%.

PS2 (your backup supply) is set to just below PS1's normal voltage. I've shown it here as 1 volt less, but the exact amount depends on how stable PS1 is.

I've shown the load as resistor just because I'm lazy.

Note that, if PS1 has a temporary dip in output voltage, PS2 will seamlessly fill in for it - it does not require that PS1 fail completely. This may or may not be a good thing. If you were to make a system which monitors PS1 and switches over in case of failure, it's easy to produce an alarm to let you know that PS1 needs attention. This is not so straightforward for this setup.

Comment: Thank you!!! Is this the diode you guys mention? http://www.ebay.com/itm/10pcs-NEW-15SQ045-10A-45V-10AMP-Schottky-Rectifiers-Diode-for-solar-panel/231519118560?_trksid=p2141725.c100338.m3726&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20141212152715%26meid%3De0d71d44477f43139b669d1667732511%26pid%3D100338%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D30%26sd%3D231398095913      Also (and sorry for the stupid question) but how do I set up the diode to intervene when the other PSU fails?

Comment: @Trescan - I expect that will work, as long as you properly heatsink them. And as long as you got what you paid for (always an issue when buying parts from China on eBay). As for setup, you use 2 of them, not one, and set them up exactly as shown.